# Using VBA to animate a scatter plot but receiving 'Range' of Object_'Global' Failed error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a simple macro to animate a scatter plot in Excel. The idea is that every second the source data range will change, thus animating the graph. My data is in columns B2:C35. Basically I wish to cycle through B2:C2, then B2:C3, then B2:C4 etc.

However, in my 'ActiveChart' line, I received the following error:

```
Method 'Range' of Object_'Global' Failed
```

Can anybody assist me here?

```
Sub animateChart()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

' In this instance, lastRow will equal 34
lastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Confirmed Cases'!$B$2:$C$") + i

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: change `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Confirmed Cases'!$B$2:$C$") + i
` to `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Confirmed Cases'!$B$2:$C$" & i)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply @HTH That simple edit did the trick. Although I then received an error `Object variable or with block variable not set`. Specifying my sheet details with `Sheets("Confirmed Cases").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate` did the job here.

Comment: you are welcome. Not sure why are you telling me that, though...

Comment: @HTT Because your suggestion wasn't a solution, and caused another problem. I am telling you how I fixed the issue your suggestion caused.

Comment: you posted only a tiny part of your code and you can't expect pepole here being responsible for what they can't see…